# What process in Rabbitmq could cause a crash when allocating memory of type "message"

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

There are a bunch of resources out there describing memory crashes due to memory allocation of the `old_heap`, but none for type `message`, does anyone know what would cause Rabbitmq on version `3.7.7` to attempt to allocate `17499422653088 bytes` of memory for this datatype?

Here's the crash dump excerpt:

```
=erl_crash_dump:0.5
Tue Nov 26 21:28:17 2019
Slogan: eheap_alloc: Cannot allocate 17499422653088 bytes of memory (of type "message").
System version: Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:16:16] [ds:16:16:10] [async-threads:256] [kernel-poll:true]
Compiled: Mon Feb  5 17:34:00 2018
Taints: crypto,asn1rt_nif,prometheus_process_collector,erl_tracer,zlib
Atoms: 37680
Calling Thread: scheduler:3
=scheduler:1
Scheduler Sleep Info Flags: SLEEPING | TSE_SLEEPING | WAITING
Scheduler Sleep Info Aux Work: DD_THR_PRGR | THR_PRGR_LATER_OP | CNCLD_TMRS_THR_PRGR
Current Port:
Run Queue Max Length: 0
Run Queue High Length: 0
Run Queue Normal Length: 0
Run Queue Low Length: 0
Run Queue Port Length: 0
Run Queue Flags: OUT_OF_WORK | HALFTIME_OUT_OF_WORK
Current Process:
=scheduler:2
Scheduler Sleep Info Flags: SLEEPING | TSE_SLEEPING | WAITING
Scheduler Sleep Info Aux Work: DD_THR_PRGR | THR_PRGR_LATER_OP
Current Port:
Run Queue Max Length: 0
Run Queue High Length: 0
Run Queue Normal Length: 0
Run Queue Low Length: 0
Run Queue Port Length: 0
Run Queue Flags: OUT_OF_WORK | HALFTIME_OUT_OF_WORK
Current Process:
=scheduler:3
Scheduler Sleep Info Flags:
Scheduler Sleep Info Aux Work: DD | DD_THR_PRGR | THR_PRGR_LATER_OP | CNCLD_TMRS_THR_PRGR
Current Port:
Run Queue Max Length: 0
Run Queue High Length: 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Run Queue Normal Length: 0
Run Queue Low Length: 0
Run Queue Port Length: 0
Run Queue Flags: OUT_OF_WORK | HALFTIME_OUT_OF_WORK | NONEMPTY | EXEC
Current Process: <0.18205.5>
Current Process State: Running
Current Process Internal State: ACT_PRIO_NORMAL | USR_PRIO_NORMAL | PRQ_PRIO_NORMAL | ACTIVE | RUNNING | ON_HEAP_MSGQ
Current Process Program counter: 0x00007f55cb464bf0 (proc_lib:proc_info/2 + 136)
Current Process CP: 0x0000000000000000 (invalid)
Current Process Limited Stack Trace:
0x00007f5332272e58:SReturn addr 0xCB461028 (proc_lib:exit_p/3 + 440)
0x00007f5332272e60:SReturn addr 0x53684948 (<terminate process normally>)
```

[image: crashdump_viewer]